# Korean characters are not showing properly

Tags: android, character-encoding

I am getting the Korean characters from input text filed in android and sending it to back end ,After saving to server the characters are not showing properly.

[image: korean][1]

I have tried different ways of encoding. I used utf-8 and ecu-kr. Nothing worked. can any one help me how to do that.

Comment: `utf-8` should be fine since it can support all Korean and Latin characters. Did you make sure that when sending the text from your app to the server the text is always encoded in `utf-8`? So when its transferred to the server, stored in the database and when it is read and when it is displayed? I suppose that at one of these steps the text is not encoded correctly

Comment: I am encoding the text and the same text sending back. do you know any other mechanism to resolve.

Comment: I don't know how exactly you implemented your application and server, so I don't know where exactly the problem could be. But `utf-8` is definitely capable of encoding Korean characters so that is not the problem.